# How to set language to htdp/bsl in REPL

Tags: racket, racket-student-languages, htdp

I have the following `htdp/bsl` program saved as `example.rkt`:

```
#lang htdp/bsl
(+ 1 1)
```

When the above is run using `racket example.rkt`, the output is as expected (i.e. `2`).

However, when I try to start an REPL with `htdp/bsl` as the language (`racket -I htdp/bsl`), the following error appears:

```
Welcome to Racket v6.3.
 default-load-handler: cannot open module file
  module path: (lib "htdp/bsl")
  path: /usr/share/racket/pkgs/htdp-lib/htdp/bsl.rkt
  system error: No such file or directory; errno=2
  context...:
```

This error does not appear when the language selected is `typed/racket`, for example.

Why does the error happen with `htdp/bsl`, and how do I correctly start an REPL with `htdp/bsl` as the language?

Comment: The short answer is that `htdp/bsl` and the teaching languages in general wasn't designed to be used that way. They are designed to be used in DrRacket.

Comment: @soegaard Is it appropriate to write BSL programs in a plain text editor and use `#lang htdp/bsl`? Or is BSL designed to be used only in DrRacket?

Comment: Depends on the type of programs you want to write. Error reporting is *much* better in DrRacket. My recommendation is to use DrRacket while learning Racket - and then switch to your preferred editor after a while.

Answer (score 6):

As @soegaard said, the htdp languages really work best in DrRacket, which I highly recommend in this case. However, if you *really* do want a REPL outside of DrRacket (say if you are grading homework and want to make a shell script for it), then you can actually use [`,enter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xrepl/index.html?q=%2Center#%28xrepl._enter%29) to get a BSL repl. Say you have a BSL file called `homework1.rkt`, which says:

```
#lang htdp/bsl
"I'm a rebel"
```

Then what you can do is open up Racket in the files directory and enter the module. In this case you'll get something like:

```
$ racket
> ,enter "homework1.bsl"
"I'm a rebel"
homework1.bsl>
```

From here you are in a BSL repl that is very similar to the one in DrRacket.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
racket -I htpd/bsl/lang example.rkt
```

to start your program (tested with Racket version 6.3.0.1).

Also, consider updating to the current version of Racket (version 6.10).

Comment: Interesting, so when I try `racket -I htdp/bsl/reader`, it tells me that it can't find (submod (lib "htdp/bsl/reader") configure-runtime)`, but that submodule clearly exists (and can be required...)